# Can I encrypt a zip file with a hashed password and decrypt it with an unhashed one?

Tags: security, encryption, zip, archive

Let's say you want your users to be able to get a package with all their data from your website once a week.

Now in order for that package to be some what secure we make a password protected zip file. (or similar popular format).

The password itself is something the user enters on the website (not related to login) but we don't want to store it in clear text so we hash it and then use the hashed bytes to encrypt the final package.

Now when unzipping the user should just use the original password they entered.

Is this possible at all - sort of like a first step hashing that the zip format would do anyway.

**Update:** The package is distributed via email, but it could be dropbox or other 3rd party service. The data should be recoverable even if my datacenter is gone. What do other sites do to provide copies of data? Are these also available when the site closes down? I think many websites could benefit with having a open+secure archive format.

Comment: What do you want your zip file to be protected against? If it is tampering (you want your packages to be authentic), plain encryption does not help. You need a MAC, a signature or an authenticated encryption, which all are different schemes with their own risk profiles and implementation details.

Comment: The zip file contains the users personal data (think GDPR or similar) right now this goes into an email as clear text with is not ideal.

Comment: That is a good point. I'd just have to educate the users not to use a secret password and not to use it anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Cryptographic hash functions are collision-resistant one-way functions, with which it is not possible to calculate the input value from its hash value.

*h(x) = y; h(y) = z*

To decrypt the zip file, the user must inevitably enter exactly the same value like you did - the hash value of its own secret (calculated with the same hash function like you used and with the same salt like you added, if you added some).

So the only way you could realize your szenario, is to inform the user about your hash-function e.g. by writing your own little "unzip-app", that you provide to the users for download. This little app takes the un-hashed passwords as input, hashes them exactly the same way you hased them on your server and then uses the hash value to open the zip file.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping that one of the available archive formats already did this. I know it was a long stretch - but you never know, could be that zip always did: HASH->ENCRYPT + HASH->DECRYPT and then I could intercept in the creation to avoid the build in hashing. The unzip app is an idea but it would have to be more of a script so that people could take a look inside and see that it was not doing something bad.

Comment: This is what I also had in my mind. Hope it will be implemented later

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is *asymmetric encryption* where a message or file is encrypted with the public key and decrypted with the private key. to the best of my knowledge, the zip file format only supports symmetric encryption (same password for encryption and decryption).

A hashed password cannot be used for encryption. It's very different from a public key. So unfortunately, your proposed approach is not working.

However, have you thought about encrypting the download channel instead of the file? Why not use the password to log into a secure section of your web page – protected by HTTPS – where the users can download the zip archive, which is not encrypted? In that case you can save the secure section login password in it's hashed form.

Yet another option is to store the sensitive passwords in a hardware security module (HSM) and have the HSM encrypt the data. HSM can be used in a way that it is impossible to retrieve the passwords. That's why they encrypt the data. That way, the passwords are safe.

Comment: I want the user to be able to recover the data the day that my site is not there anymore. Thats why I'm sending them an email with the data inside each week. Today thats cleartext which is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, you might want to check out "age".
Public and private key can be generated with ssh-keygen.
Am giving my excerpt with below commands for debian. Once the zip file is encrypted with public key, it cannot be decrypted with anything other than its corresponding private key. So even if the interceptor in the middle has the encrypted file and the public key with which it was encrypted, he won't be able to decrypt it.
Refer https://github.com/FiloSottile/age

```
# on both sides
sudo apt install age
# on the sender side
age -e -R receiver_public_key_file.pub -o file.zip.age file.zip
# on the receiver side
age -d -i receiver_private_key -o file.zip file.zip.age
```